# Using a label to depict the status of a form

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a situation where all I need is a label that switches between "Ready" and "In progress" when a user clicks a button. The label is intially in the "Ready" state. When the user clicks a button, the label should read "In progress" then some tasks need to be performed, like copying files etc. After the tasks are completed successfully the label should once again read "Ready". Right now I am using this piece of code and the label status does not change. How can I make this work. Please help.

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
        status.Text = "In Progress";
        if (listBox1.Items.Count == 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please select a file to upload");
        }
        FtpClient client = new FtpClient("*******", "*******", "******");
        string fileName = getFileNameFromPath(listBox1.Items[0].ToString());
        string localFile = listBox1.Items[0].ToString();
        string remoteFile = "**********/"+fileName;
        string link = client.upload(remoteFile, localFile);
        listBox1.Items.RemoveAt(0);
        textBox1.Text = link; 
        status.Text = "Ready";  
  }
```

Comment: Call Application.DoEvents just after you set the status.text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're blocking the UI thread during your long running process, both preventing the UI from updating the text value, or receiving user input, or doing *anything* for that matter.

You need to do the long running work asynchronously so as to not block the UI thread.

Ideally you'd have an asynchronous method provided by your `FtpClient` (and even better, it would return a `Task`).  This would allow you to write something like this:

```
private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    status.Text = "In Progress";
    if (listBox1.Items.Count == 0)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please select a file to upload");
    }
    FtpClient client = new FtpClient("*******", "*******", "******");
    string fileName = getFileNameFromPath(listBox1.Items[0].ToString());
    string localFile = listBox1.Items[0].ToString();
    string remoteFile = "**********/" + fileName;
    string link = await client.uploadAsync(remoteFile, localFile);
    listBox1.Items.RemoveAt(0);
    textBox1.Text = link;
    status.Text = "Ready";
}
```

And then you'd be done.  If it doesn't provide any asynchronous methods then, as a work around, you can just start up a new task to do the work in the background:

```
private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    status.Text = "In Progress";
    if (listBox1.Items.Count == 0)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please select a file to upload");
    }
    FtpClient client = new FtpClient("*******", "*******", "******");
    string fileName = getFileNameFromPath(listBox1.Items[0].ToString());
    string localFile = listBox1.Items[0].ToString();
    string remoteFile = "**********/" + fileName;
    string link = await Task.Run(() => client.upload(remoteFile, localFile));
    listBox1.Items.RemoveAt(0);
    textBox1.Text = link;
    status.Text = "Ready";
}
```

If you don't have C# 5.0 and .NET 4.5 to be able to use `await` then you can use a `BackgroundWorker`:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    status.Text = "In Progress";
    if (listBox1.Items.Count == 0)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please select a file to upload");
    }
    string fileName = getFileNameFromPath(listBox1.Items[0].ToString());
    string localFile = listBox1.Items[0].ToString();
    string remoteFile = "**********/" + fileName;
    var worker = new BackgroundWorker();
    worker.DoWork += (s, args) =>
    {
        FtpClient client = new FtpClient("*******", "*******", "******");
        args.Result =  client.upload(remoteFile, localFile);
    };
    worker.RunWorkerCompleted += (s, args) =>
    {
        listBox1.Items.RemoveAt(0);
        textBox1.Text = args.Result as string;
        status.Text = "Ready";
    };
    worker.RunWorkerAsync();
}
```

Comment: I get a few compilation errors when I tried this second approach, doesn't seem to agree to using 'await' and does not allow using async in my method signature.

Comment: @Sai This particular solution requires having C# 5.0 and .NET 4.5.  If you do not, and your FTP client doesn't have built in asynchronous support of some kind, then you would need to use a `BackgroundWorker`.  Upload the file in the `DoWork` handler and update the textbox in the `RunWorkerCompleted` event handler.

Comment: Thanks a lot. My problem is I dont know how to transfer control from a button click to the do work of a background worker.For eg. here, the upload process starts after user clicks the button, how do I call the do work in the button click event handler?

Comment: @Sai Example added.  It's simple enough if you just use lambdas instead of actual named methods.

Comment: Thanks for the example. But unfortunately the label status never changed. It remained "ready" throughout.

Comment: @Sai As it stands it won't update until after you confirm the message box, is that what you're referring to?

Comment: I am extremely sorry. It was an oversight on my part. It worked like a charm. Thanks for educating me.